# Unable to insert data into MySQL via php file

Tags: php, mysql

I understand that such questions have been downvoted or closed, however I've been through all the previously asked questions and couldn't find any solutions. The code is supposed to accept input from a HTML form and insert it into the MySQL database and be displayed on another page, but somehow I end up with query failed statement and redirected to the Login page.

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['eTransport_ID'])){
            $id = ($_POST['eTransport_ID']);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['Phone_No'])){
            $phone = ($_POST['Phone_No']);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['Amount'])){
            $amount = ($_POST['Amount']);
        }
        $DATEE = date("Y-m-d");
        $TIMEE = date("h:i:sa");

        $query = "INSERT INTO recharge_history(Date, Time, Amount, Agent_No, eTransport_ID) VALUES ('$DATEE', '$TIMEE', '$amount', 'WEB', '$id')";
        $added = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if(!$added){
            die("Database query failed.");
        }
        else{
            echo "Data Entered Successfully";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

---

[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeNCM.jpg)

Comment: echo your `$query` and try manually running it to your dbms

Comment: try{
   $query goes here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
print_r($e);
}

Comment: you will get an idea where issue is there in your statement

Comment: This is wrong advice @jackbrone. mysql_query doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: Try this example will help you find error.                                                    
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$query = "INSERT INTO recharge_history(Date, Time, Amount, Agent_No, eTransport_ID) VALUES ('$DATEE', '$TIMEE', '$amount', 'WEB', '$id')";

Can you write query like this

$query = "INSERT INTO recharge_history(Date, Time, Amount, Agent_No, eTransport_ID) VALUES ($DATEE, $TIMEE, $amount, $phone, $id)";

Answer (score 0):

1. This is BAD code which has severe SQL injection vulnerabilities so please look into that separately (your question isn't about security)
2. I'm assuming 'Date' is a DATE column
3. I'm assuming 'Time' is a TIME column
4. It looks as though Agent_No may be an INT column, but you're inserting a string.  I've substituted for a "1" so you'll have to look at that separately.

If my assumptions are correct, just change the query line to exactly this (ie: copy and paste it):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO recharge_history (`Date`, `Time`, `Amount`, `Agent_No`, `eTransport_ID`) VALUES (NOW(), NOW(), $amount, 'WEB', $id)";
```

Comment: The agent number previously was previous INT data type but I changed it to VARCHAR due to the assumption that Top up agents recharge the ID Cards via a machine so they will have an agent number, and to differentiate with web top up, I decided to input 'WEB' to indicate the topup was done through the web page. However, I did try your suggestion but it did not work unfortunately :(